# get_permalink to attachment not working

Tags: attachment, permalinks

I have following code:

```
    <?php

      $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => 12,
   'post_status' => null
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $attachment->ID ).'">';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array('100', '100') );
          echo '</a></li>';
          }
     }

?>
```

The point of this script is to show last added 12 photos (thumbs of it). And this works perfect. But I want to add second funcionality - link to the page where it comes from (usually native gallery embed into post/page)

The problem is that in this case the link is corrupted. It always links to the very first post. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`get_attachment_link($attachment->ID)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link).

Or [`the_attachment_link($attachment->ID`)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_attachment_link) to directly print the anchor tag with the URL

Comment: Using get_attachment_link($attachment->ID) changed situation a bit. thanks to that I received URLS like:
http://domain.com/gallery/post-name/attachement/img-30121/

How to remove part "attachement/..."?

Comment: I don't think you can do that easily, because it's part of built-in rewrite rules. Check out your permalink settings, or search for a plugin that gives you more control over the permalinks...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final version:)

```
    <?php

      $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => 12,
   'post_status' => null
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           $url = get_permalink( $attachment->ID );
          echo '<li><a href="'.strstr($url, '/attachment', true).'">';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array('100', '100') );
          echo '</a></li>';       
          }
     }

?>
```

/attachment is the starting point from which we want to remove everything from the url.